# Ordenar Matriz CSV por fecha Python

Tags: python, lista, csv, matrices

Estoy haciendo un pequeño desarrollo, en cual leo desde un archivo CSV de esta forma:

```
    csv = np.genfromtxt('MMRExport.csv',delimiter=",", dtype=str)
```

Luego lo que hago es crear listas ya que solo necesito 2 columnas del archivo, una de "fecha" y otra de "mensaje". La lista de mensajes la dejo igual, pero la de fecha como era string la transformo a fecha así:

```
   Date[i]= datetime.strptime(Date[i], '%d-%b-%Y')
```

De esta forma, las posiciones de los elementos "mensaje" y "fecha" son las mismas, pero en listas diferentes.

Pero hoy me acabo de dar cuenta que debo ordenar las fechas de forma creciente (de la más antigua a la más nueva). Mi pregunta es ¿puedo hacer una matriz que tenga en un lado el "mensaje" y su "fecha", de esta forma al ordenar las fechas también se ordenan los mensajes, o existe alguna forma de ordenar las "fechas" pero sin perder el orden de los "mensajes"?

Comment: puedes probar: `ordenada = lista.sort(key = lambda x : x[1])`, el parámetro key recibe una función anónima en la que puedes especificar la columna a utilizar para ordenar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por tu ejemplo entiendo que lees el CSV en un [numpy.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#the-n-dimensional-array-ndarray), pero luego pareciera ser que del mismo armas dos listas separadas para `mensaje` y `fecha`. Efectivamente ordenar una de las listas no te ordena automáticamente la otra, por lo que lo más conveniente es mantener ambos datos juntos en una lista de listas. Te muestro un ejemplo basado en tu pregunta

Primero armamos un [numpy.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#the-n-dimensional-array-ndarray) a modo de ejemplo, con datos similares a los que mencionas, más o menos lo que obtendrías de  `csv = np.genfromtxt('MMRExport.csv',delimiter=",", dtype=str)`

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pprint

def dt (s):
  return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d')

x = np.array([
              ["mensaje 1", dt('20170121')],
              ["mensaje 2", dt('20170101')],
              ["mensaje 3", dt('20170131')]
            ])
```

Por lo que comentas en algún momento pasas a trabajar con dos listas Python de los datos recién leídos, no es necesario hacer eso, puedes manejar una única lista donde cada elemento es otra lista con ambos campos. Mediante `numpy` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
lista = x.tolist()
pprint.pprint(lista)
```

Con lo que obtienes lo siguiente:

```
[['mensaje 1', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 21, 0, 0)],
 ['mensaje 2', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0)],
 ['mensaje 3', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 31, 0, 0)]]
```

Aclaración: estoy usando `pprint` por que formatea mucho mejor particularmente listas y objetos similares.

Con esto es muy simple ordenar, ya Jose Hermosilla Rodrigo te dió una pauta en un comentario:

```
# Sort sencillo sobre una lista de listas 
lista.sort(key = lambda x : x[1])
pprint.pprint(lista)
```

A la función `sort` se le pasa un función anónima que determina el dato que se utilizará para ordenar, en nuestro ejemplo la columna de la fecha (indice = 1).
Es importante notar que el sort es "in place" o sea, se ordena directamente la lista, si necesitarás quedarte con el orden original hay que hacer una copia antes de ordenar o usar [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-how-to). El resultado final, es la lista completa ordenada por fecha:

```
[['mensaje 2', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0)],
 ['mensaje 1', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 21, 0, 0)],
 ['mensaje 3', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 31, 0, 0)]]
```

Por último, si decidieras hacer todo desde el objeto `numpy` también tienes esta posibilidad:

```
x = x[x[:, 1].argsort()]
pprint.pprint(x)
```

En este caso el orden no es "in place" por lo que hacemos una asignación para mantenerlo, la salida es algo distinta pero el orden es el mismo

```
array([['mensaje 2', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0)],
       ['mensaje 1', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 21, 0, 0)],
       ['mensaje 3', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 31, 0, 0)]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Está muy buena tu respuesta, entendiste perfecto mi pregunta. Gracias!